# changing the default sort on jqgrid

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

There is probably a quick solution here but i couldn't find it....

I want to change the default sorting when clicking on the column header from 'asc' to 'desc',

I tried adding this code, it changes the direction of the sorting but still the icon of the arrow is opposite:

```
onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
    sortOrder = (sortOrder == 'asc' ? sortOrder = 'desc' : sortOrder = 'asc');
    jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({ sortorder: sortOrder })
}
```

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `firstsortorder:'desc'` in the definition of every column of the [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options).

Comment: Thanks very much for your great answer!  I've been googling for hours without any luck and this nailed it.  Just in case there are some poor other Googlers i was searching for:
jqgrid reverse column click sort.

Comment: @Oleg Is there any way to set this globally?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, you can use `$extend($.jgrid.defaults, {firstsortorder: "desc"});` to modify global settings. In the way you can modify default values of any jqGrid parameter.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your help...just implemented this to add in a ajaxGridOption gloabally...huge help.  One small nitpick just for the next person.  `$entend` should be `$.extend` (Just so someone else doesn't get hung up, etc. )

Comment: @Mark: You are welcome! The `$extend` instead of `$.extend` (`jQuery.extend`) was of cause typing error. Thanks!